# Reading the content of the stream "Stream" using "ReadToEnd()" in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I have a function which has an input parameter of type "stream".
I want to read the content of this stream and compare to a content of a file.
The following has been done:

```
public bool func(Stream stream, string tempFilePath, string dstFilePath)
{
    string[] File1 = File.ReadAllLines(tempFilePath);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    int line = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string[] File2 = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(
        new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, 
        StringSplitOptions.None                                                                        
    );

    while (line < File1.Length)
    {
        if (astFile2[line] != astFile1[line])
            break;

        line++;
    }

    bool ret = line == astFile1.Length && line == astFile2.Length - 1;
    if (ret )
    {
        using (var dstFile = new FileStream(dstFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
            stream.CopyTo(dstFile );
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that I can't take the content of the variable "stream" anymore using the command:
        "stream.CopyTo(dstFile ); "
The content is empty!

The "position" of the stream using the `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` is correct. 
I have used the `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` command after the `ReadToEnd()` line, but it did not help.
I have used also the `stream.Position = 0`, and did not help too.
That why I think there should be no problem by position.

What is it missed in this code?
Why the `ReadToEnd()` command results in emptying the `stream`?

For test, I also did the following:

```
  string[] File2 = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(
                                            new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                            StringSplitOptions.None
                                        );


  stream.Position = 0;
   string[] File3 = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(
                                            new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                            StringSplitOptions.None
                                        );
```

The content of "File3" is still empty!

Comment: You used `reader.ReadToEnd()` which moves the stream pointer to the end, and you didn't reset it to the start before calling `stream.CopyTo()`.

Comment: That did not help, as I mentioned in the post, by using stream.Position = 0

Comment: That's not actually in the code you posted. Why are you not posting the actual code that you're using? It makes it hard to read if you have to mentally edit the code based on some comments in a different part of your question...

Comment: You already have the contents of the stream in `File2` - why don't you write those instead of rereading the stream?

Comment: I have to read the content directly for some reasons. What is strange, is why is it not possible to use the  ReadToEnd() more than one time for the same stream in my described case above.

Comment: Where is the stream coming from? Some streams can only be read once...

Comment: It is memorystream created by another function

Comment: Are you sure the stream is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not showing us the actual faulty code.

I have paraphrased your code to a compilable console app, which does NOT reproduce the problem:

```
using System.IO;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourceFile = @"D:\tmp\source.txt";
            string destFile   = @"D:\tmp\dest.txt";

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            var data = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;

            func(ms, sourceFile, destFile);
        }

        public static void func(Stream stream, string tempFilePath, string dstFilePath)
        {
            File.ReadAllLines(tempFilePath);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var dstFile = new FileStream(dstFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(dstFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm afraid that the answer to the question "what is missed in this code?" is "a reproducable problem".

It is crucial that you tell us the concrete type of the `Stream` that you are passing to `func()`. It is likely that is the cause of your problem - for example, it's a stream that can only be read once (although in that case, trying to change the stream position should really throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Comment: The stream is created by a function which I do not have an access to, but it is a memorystream, and I did not get the UnsupportedOperationException. That why I thought that it is possible to read many times. I have posted the exact function that I have used, and getting the problem.

Comment: `I have posted the exact function that I have used` - no, you haven't. The code you posted can't compile. For example, `lineNum` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I always make sure I call stream.Flush() before doing a ReadToEnd().